# Adding Id number using group_by() in R

Tags: r, group-by, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that's formatted like so:

| evaluation | grouping |
| --- | --- |
| 1.00 | a |
| 0.50 | a |
| 2.00 | b |
| 1.00 | b |
| 2.00 | b |
| 0.50 | c |

I want to create a new column with ID numbers for each grouping like so:

| evaluation | grouping | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.00 | a | 1 |
| 0.50 | a | 1 |
| 2.00 | b | 2 |
| 1.00 | b | 2 |
| 2.00 | b | 2 |
| 0.50 | c | 3 |

I have attempted this code:

```
data$id <- data %>% group_by(grouping) %>% 1:nrow(data) %>% ungroup
```

Comment: I think the canonical method would be to use `dplyr::cur_group_id`, as PaulS's (currently-deleted) answer shows. For instance, `df %>% group_by(grouping) %>% mutate(id = cur_group_id())` will give you your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without `group_by`.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(ID = match(grouping, unique(grouping)))
#>   evaluation grouping ID
#> 1        1.0        a  1
#> 2        0.5        a  1
#> 3        2.0        b  2
#> 4        1.0        b  2
#> 5        2.0        b  2
#> 6        0.5        c  3
```